# Not receiving push notifications in background, only foreground (no alerts)

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I've set up my app for `push notifications`, and for the past few days of development I've received zero notifications when the app is in the background. `No alert, badges, sounds -- nada`. Nothing shows up in the notifications area when you swipe down the screen from above.

But when the app is in the foreground, `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` does indeed fire off. When I first started messing around with notifications, I was getting them, but at some point it just stopped working. I've verified that the phone has notifications enabled for the app.

I'm using Quickblox to send cross-platform push notifications, and they have a control panel on their website where you can send notifications. When I sent one through there, I receive it in the background. On the foreground, this is what I see as the log output for the ones sent from the control panel:

```
2015-07-11 00:11:26.755 Viewerapp[6671:2177549] didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo={
    aps =     {
        alert = "Testing push notification";
        sound = default;
    };
}
```

And this is what I receive when the client app uses the Quickblox API to send a push notification:

```
2015-07-11 00:14:14.907 Viewerapp[6671:2177549] didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo={
    QBUserID = 2574021;
    aps =     {
        alert = "";
    };
    messageOS = Android;
    messageText = "Push notification test";
    messageType = "simpleMessage";
    userName = John;
}
```

Is the problem that the latter lacks data in `aps`? Does it seem like it's a Quickblox issue?